# php POST can't handle <img src="http://

Tags: php, mysql, html, insert

I'm creating a form where the user should be able to enter any text (used to change articles on the site), Html, JavaScript or literally anything is allowed to type in and post, and so far everything worked. But today I suddenly got this strange error.

When I try to save text with Html to a MySQL database like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">google</a>
```

nothing goes wrong, but when I try it like this:

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/" />
```

The page does not load (forbidden error) and the database does not contain any of the text is should contain (the Html).

Instead the page shows the following error:

> Forbidden
>       You do not have permission to access this document.

The same problem occurs when I try to post the following data:

```
src="http:
```

Why do I get a forbidden error when the post contains that specific piece of text, whats going on here?

**Code I'm using:**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" && !empty($_POST['save'])){
    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textarea']);
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO articles (text, title) VALUES ('".$text."','".$title."')";
```

When I remove the MySQL query I still get the error so it has nothing to do with the database. PHP safe mode is on, could that make a difference?

How can this be fixed?

**Edit:** Tried the complete application on my xampp server and it did not show the error, but on my hosting server I use the script in a password protected map. could that be the problem? Anyway I'm going to contact my hosting company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds a bit like [mod_security](https://modsecurity.org/), switched on and in its most aggressive mode, and it thinks you're trying to hack the site. The reason I say it only sounds a *bit* like that is because no-one should normally configure it to check POST data because that causes far too many false positives. But check the error log(s) as it will probably be listed there if it's that. If so you'll need to turn it off in the hosting settings or nag your host to do it.

Also try a bare minimum script: `<?php var_dump($GLOBALS); ?>` to see if the data reaches PHP at all.

Comment: Thanks,
i tried the var_dump, and removed any other php code. still get the same error. I should contact my hosting company. Or first try it on my home server.

Comment: Yup it was the modsecurity ;(

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['save'])){
$text = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['textarea']));
$title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['title']));
```

Answer (score -1):

Send this into your db

```
<a href=www.google.com>Google</a>
```

or

When called from db

```
echo "http://".$row_TabelName['RowName'];
```

It should solve your issue.

Comment: I know I've already downvoted the answers here, but I can't make any sense of this one at all. Once again, corrupting or altering the raw data is just a bad solution. What is the significance of `http://<a href=www.google.com>Google</a>`?

Comment: Could be a nice if the field would only contain the img tag, but it does contain a lot more html.

Comment: The error is appearing because of the "". remove it, it should work fine, its coding issue not a sql error.  It's not corrupting or altering the raw data, but predicting the user input.  If the user used '' then?

Comment: Jean, imagine that instead of HTML, the data is a string like `Quotes are "essential" sometimes`, then what? Or how about, as OP said, a lot of HTML? Besides, sometimes quotes are *required* to remove ambiguity in HTML, for instance: `<option class=myclass selected>`... Is that `class="myclass selected"` or `class="myclass" selected`

Answer (score -2):

if you wish to use the following

`base64encode()` and insert ,after read `base64decode()`

Comment: You probably should not corrupt your raw data like this to work around this very significant problem (or probably ever). Are you going to `base64encode()` all your query parameters for the rest of the application's lifetime so you can do a simple `WHERE` or `LIKE`? Besides OP noted that `When I remove the MySQL query I still get the error so it has nothing to do with the database`. Interesting idea, but in practice this is quite awful.